# Mods in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are congruent modulo $24$, that is, $x \equiv y\ (mod\ 24)$.

Which of the following is **not** guaranteed to be true?

a. $x$ and $y$ have the same last digit in binary notation

b. $x$ and $y$ have the same last digit in decimal notation

c. $(x \mod 3) = (y \mod 3)$

d. Both $x ≡ y (mod\ 6)$  and $x ≡ y (mod\ 8)$ are true.

From just trying to understand the problem I concluded that (b) and (c) are guaranteed to be true. But what steps can I take to logically answer this question?

Comment: You are supposed to use $x\equiv y$ (mod 24) to try to show the other 4 statements.

Likewise, if you can find any counterexamples to any of the 4 statements that satisfy $x\equiv y$ (mod 24), then that statement you found a counterexample to is false.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
(b) consider 24 and 48.

Note that 2,3,6 and 8 are divisors of 24, while 10 is not.

Comment: ok. But if x and y are congruent, and if they have the same last digit (24 and 144 for example), then it's true.

Comment: @Varoag no. You need it to be true for *all* choices of $x,y$...